# HttpOnly Secure Cookies not being sent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, httponly

Yes, another question about httpOnly Cookies.

Like a lot of other people, i'm stuck at the same place.

I get the cookie from the server but it is never sent with other requests.
I have mysite.example.com in angularjs trying to connect to api.example.com.

Here is the response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://mysite.example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2855
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 09 Jun 2021 00:52:54 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.46 (Amazon) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips
Set-Cookie: WEB-TOKEN=158b691a-65fb-49c2-9d88-63bd1935531f;Version=1;Comment=;Max-Age=3600;Secure;HttpOnly;Expires=Wed, 09 Jun 2021 00:52:54 GMT
vary: Origin
```

Then, in AngularJS, i send a request like this (from mysite.example.com):

```
$http.get('https://api.example.com/userdetails', { withCredentials: true, headers: {  } });
```

Is there anything not sent or just wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Path. Yes. I was missing the Path to %x2F. :)